# Running SSIS packages as SQL Server Agent Job failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-agent-job

it is the first time and my first post in "stackoverflow" and I hope, that you can help me regarding my project.

Once I start the corresponding Job in SSMS, which I have created, I get the following error message:

> Executed as user: XXXX Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package
> Utility  Version 13.0.5026.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft.
> All rights reserved.    Started:  15:36:23  Error: 2021-10-11
> 15:36:23.51     Code: 0xC0011007     Source:
> {BE14993C-9347-4920-8C3C-97E254866D05}      Description: Unable to
> load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML
> format. A specific XML parser error will be posted.  End Error  Error:
> 2021-10-11 15:36:23.51     Code: 0xC0011002     Source:
> {BE14993C-9347-4920-8C3C-97E254866D05}      Description: Failed to
> open package file "D:\Test\XXX.dtsx" due to error 0x80070003 "The
> system cannot find the path specified.".  This occurs when loading a
> package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML
> document. This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name
> when calling LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect
> format.  End Error  Could not load package "D:\Test\XXXX.dtsx" because
> of error 0xC0011002.  Description: Failed to open package file
> "D:\Test\XXXX.dtsx" due to error 0x80070003 "The system cannot find
> the path specified.".  This occurs when loading a package and the file
> cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can
> be the result of specifying an incorrect file name when calling
> LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.
> Source: {BE14993C-9347-4920-8C3C-97E254866D05}  Started:  15:36:23
> Finished: 15:36:23  Elapsed:  0.016 seconds.  The package could not be
> found.  The step failed.

I have already tried the following points:

- The permissions which I log in on the appropriate server, etc.
- I have created a "Credential" & "Proxy" and configurated/managed it
- Check the **"DelayValidation" in Visual Studio (is "True")**
- TargetServerVersion is on **"SQL Server 2019"**
- Security => ProtectionLevel is on **"EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey"**

Many thanks for your assist.

Best Regards,
Safak

Comment: The RunAs (usually agent) needs access to the network folder.

Comment: Many thanks KeithL :-)
The problem was fixed ;-)

Comment: If the problem is fixed, you can self-answer to share how to fix your issue, and help people that will have same that your own

Comment: How did you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

- I see that the path of the package using is a path server server. If that's the case replace it with UNC path in format //machinename/ c$/...
- The account executing package from job has no access to path. If that's the case give account access to the path